# simplemodal window covered up by embedded youtube video

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm trying to use the simple modal jquery library on a page and the modal popup is being hidden behind an embedded youtube object on my page. I tried messing around with z-index, but couldn't figure this out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [simple modal page](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/):

> To prevent Flash objects from "bleeding through" the dialog, make sure to set the wmode property for your object and embed elements to either opaque or transparent ([reference](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=e5141)).

Comment: Karim is correct - you need to modify the flash embedding code.

Answer (score 1):

```
function hideFlash() {
    var embeds = document.getElementsByTagName('embed');
    for (i = 0; i < embeds.length; i++) {
        embeds[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
    for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        objects[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
};

function showFlash() {
    var embeds = document.getElementsByTagName('embed');
    for (i = 0; i < embeds.length; i++) {
        embeds[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
    for (i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        objects[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
    }

    var iframes = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    iframes[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
};
```

Comment: Welcome on SO, here, it is a good practice to explain why to use your solution and not just how. That will make your answer more valuable and help further reader to have a better understanding of how you do it. I also suggest that you have a look on our FAQ : http://stackoverflow.com/faq.